How to insert values into a table that has an autogenerated column
I have a table named "liverpool_players" and I'm trying to create a new one with an additional column "years_at_club", which I mean for to be autogenerated as at date 31 Dec 2024. I run the following sql statements in PostgreSQL:
create table liverpool_players_new
(
    name varchar(30),
    age int,
    position varchar(10),
    club_debut date,
    years_at_club decimal(4,2) GENERATED ALWAYS as (('2024-12-31' - club_debut)/365.25) STORED,
    country varchar(20)
);

insert into liverpool_players_new 
    (select name, age, position, club_debut, [WHAT GOES HERE?], country 
     from liverpool_players);

Thing is I have no idea what to put in the "years_at_club" field when copying values from the old table. When I put a value (whether calculated or just any dummy decimal number) I get an error that the column is autogenerated and thus should not be populated. When I omit the field altogether I get an error that the dimensions don't match (as expected). Weird enough, when I put the "years_at_club" column at the end in the CREATE TABLE statement and then omit its value in the INSERT INTO statement it works just fine!
Like so:
create table liverpool_players_new
(
    name varchar(30),
    age int,
    position varchar(10),
    club_debut date,
    country varchar(20),
    years_at_club decimal(4,2) GENERATED ALWAYS as (('2024-12-31' - club_debut)/365.25) STORED
);

insert into liverpool_players_new 
    (select name, age, position, club_debut, country 
     from liverpool_players);

But I'm stubborn and I want to be able to choose freely the exact position of my years_at_club column! :)
Any help would be appreciated please. Thank you in advance

specify your target column list, leaving out the autogenerated column - insert into <table> (list of target columns) select <stuff> from <some table>...

Always write down the list of columns you want to fill by your insert command, no matter if those are two, columns, five or all. This avoids this issue and every other possible issue which could occur in case someone added a column, but you haven't extended your code.

The Backus Naur form of SQL query command's syntax is as:
INSERT [ INTO ] <table> [ ( <list_of_target_columns> ) 
{ VALUES ( <value_list> ) 
  | <SELECT_query> }

Yous mixed query and value list. Also if any column is auto generated, yous have the choice to avoid this column in the <list_of_target_columns>
In your case you must use the optional <list_of_target_columns> and avoid the "years_at_club" columns name in the list or replace the value of the "years_at_club" column by the key word DEFAULT if you use a value_list
So the correct query must be:
INSERT INTO liverpool_players_new 
      (name, age, position, club_debut, country)
SELECT name, age, position, club_debut, country 
FROM   liverpool_players);



The insert..values list lets you specify default.  demo at db<>fiddle
insert into liverpool_players_new
values('name1', 20, 'position1', current_date, default, 'country1');

Unfortunately, that's not allowed in an insert..select, as underlined under @JGH's example.

Skip the column if you told your insert what's what in the input, listing target columns:
insert into liverpool_players_new(name, age, position, club_debut, country)
select name, age, position, club_debut, country from liverpool_players;

...as immediately pointed out by @Andrew and expanded on by @SQLpro.

Put the table behind an updatable view that skips the column, target that view instead:
create view v_liverpool_players_new as 
select name, age, position, club_debut, country from liverpool_players_new;

insert into v_liverpool_players_new
select name, age, position, club_debut, country from liverpool_players;


Look up the default or generated expression in pg_attrdef system catalog and reconstruct it with pg_get_expr(adbin, adrelid) if you need this for dynamic SQL statements.
select pg_get_expr(adbin, adrelid) 
from pg_attrdef as ad
join pg_attribute as a
  on a.attrelid=ad.adrelid
where ad.adrelid='liverpool_players_new'::regclass
  and a.attname='years_at_club';




pg_get_expr




((('2024-12-31'::date - club_debut))::numeric / 365.25)






In addition to specifying the column names, you can also use the default value:
insert into liverpool_players_new (name, age, position, club_debut, years_at_club, country) 
 values ('test',1,'test', current_date, default, 'test');


NO...  DEFAULT value is not possible for SELECT queries for INSERTs
